# How to style a <select> to the default -webkit-appearance?

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

Currently, my select looks like this<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pkw0.png)</sup>,
however, I would like to have it look like this<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ghTt.png)</sup>, the default iOS select dropdown.
The problem I think is, that I cannot edit all of the code, some is locked (I'm using WordPress).

Here's my code:

```
-webkit-appearance: menulist !important;
border: 0;
```

and here's the default code:

```
height: 40px;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: normal;
color: #000;
margin: 0;
background: #fff;
width: 100%;
padding: 0 10px;
text-align: left;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

If I delete this code from the DOM, the select looks the way I want it to, but how can I achieve this look given the circumstances with CSS or Javascript?

Comment: So you created a child theme, put the 1st snippet in a suitable CSS rule in style.css but it's still overridden? I'm not sure what exactly the issue is here. You posted CSS but you're still asking how to do it with CSS?

Comment: @ChrisG My problem is kind of that I don't know which values will change back the <select> to its iOS-like style. It obviously has to do with background and border, but 0, none and transparent don't work in the way that the styling is back to it's original. If I delete background and border its styled like iOS (which I want).